# Make a responsive image next to a text for smaller screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I have a responsive image in Bootstrap (3.3.7):

```
 <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
     <img class="img-responsive center-block " src="img/1.png" style="max-width:
     <p>Some guarantee text here</p>
</div>
```

which appears something like this:

[image]

How can I make it appears NEXT to the text for smaller screens? So basically this:

[image]

I understand that `img-responsive` adds `display: block`, so i tried overwriting that with an inline style, but it didn't work.

Comment: You can handle it by changing the structure to next: `img` and `textz are two blocks next to each other nested in `.row` then you assign them something like `col-4` and `col-8` for smaller screens and `col-12` both for bigger ones

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do that by using `float:left;` read more from [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/float/)

```html
 <div class="col-sm-2 text-center" >
     <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7CuQ.jpg" style="float:left;margin:4px;    width: 120px;">
     <p>Some guarantee text here</p>
     <p>Some sdasd</p>
</div>
```